# Suggestion for error report in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a table called `candidate`. I entered the candidate details its going to add the table also. If I click the `Save` button it shows an error

> Object reference not set to an object

But in table the details are added.

Please help me to come out this problem.

Comment: You wil have to show some of the code being executed for us to have a look.

Comment: Put the code that and the full error stack in the question.

Comment: Solution: **debug your code** - step through it, see where and why you get that `NullReferenceException`. Without even seeing your code, no one here can be of assistance....